# TYPO3: Reading tt_address and print it sorted by sys_categories with fluid in own extbase extension

Tags: typo3, relation, fluid, extbase

I want to read the contents of tt_address and print them sorted by sys_categories in my own extbase/fluid extension.

I mapped both tables in typoscript, created models, controllers and repositories for both and so I am able to print both tables complete without issues.

However, I need to print only the adresses that match a certain category (depends on the page) but I can't get it to work.

According to some research it should be posible to load them and access them in the fluid template like

```
    <f:for each="{cats}" as="cat">
      <f:for each="{cat.items}" as="adr">{adr}</f:for>
    </f:for>
```

But if I display them via the debug option there a no adresses attached to the cat array - no wonder that none are displayed.

I created TCAs for both tables with only the M:M related column definition in it (categories for tt_address and items for sys_categories) and I included the following in the models:

```
    /**
     * Addresses
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Address>
     */
     protected $addresses;

     /**
      * Adds a Address
      *
      * @param \Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Address $address
      * @return void
      */
      public function addAddress(\Vendor\Myext\Address\Domain\Model\Address $address) {
       $this->addresses->attach($address);
      }

    /**
     * Removes a Address
     *
     * @param \Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Address $addressToRemove The Address to be removed
     * @return void
     */
     public function removeAddress(\Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Address $addressToRemove) {
      $this->addresses->detach($addressToRemove);
     }

    /**
     * Returns the Addresses
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Address> $addresses
     */
     public function getAddresses() {
      return $this->addresses;
     }

    /**
     * Sets the Addresses
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Address> $addresses
     * @return void
     */
     public function setAddresses(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $addresses) {
      $this->addresses = $addresses;
     }
```

and of course the other way round in the address-model.

Where is the fault, what am I missing? Is it even possible to use M:M relations on mapped tables? Do I need a complete TCA?

Please help I'm trying this desperately since one week. Each answer will be appreciated very much.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I want to use the "sys_category_record_mm"-relationship table of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add categories to the tt_address table  with `makeCategorizable()`?

This will add the correct TCA for you on tt_address so you don't have to worry about the MM raltaions.
You then also can just fetch all needed records based on certain parameters . in your case, the category of your page. And you can also create category collections to push to your view .

all is explained in here : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html

Comment: Thank you so much - it works now! :-)

For all others running into a similar situation:

You don't need to map the categories table nor the mm table, you don't need to create model, repository or controller for them and you don't have to write any TCA.

Just call _"makeCategorizable()"_ in _ext_tables.php_ and create a member variable with getters and setters for the categories in your model - that's all!

Comment: I also want to use categories, but I have an issue. Added `makeCategorizable()`, added sql column for my model, but when I add `protected $categories;` with seters and geters to my model, I get an exception in frontend, even if I don't access it. `#1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "": PHP Warning: class_parents(): object or string expected in .../typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/‌​DataMapper.php line 283`. What I am doing wrong?
https://gist.github.com/iamandrewluca/52a447d65eff1ea2e739118cd5b9ff15

Comment: Got it done https://gist.github.com/iamandrewluca/7b9a7a3d5463f6f27f668eb2fcdda1ad